# storing data with header in csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to store some data in csv file. I am able to store data but it looks like this

```
1901,1909,1911,1913,1917
5,5,5,4,6
```

the first row is year names and second row is values.
my code is as follow

```
import os
import csv
from collections import Counter
from csv import reader


def read_data(filename):
    year = 3
    with open(filename) as f:
        next(f, None)  # discard header
        year2rel = Counter(int(line[YEAR]) for line in reader(f))
        return year2rel

file_exists = os.path.isfile('mycsvfile.csv')
def store_data(value):
    my_dict = read_data(filename)
    print 'my_dict: ', my_dict
    with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as f:
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
        if not file_exists:
            w.writeheader()
        print 'w: ', w
        w.writerow(my_dict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = '/home/rob/songs_detail.csv'
    a = read_songs(filename)
    b = store_data(a)
```

but I want to include headers so that it looks like

```
year values
1901 5
1909 5
1911 5
1913 4
1917 6
```

I tried to change my code but it doesn't work for me well. I tried something like below but unsuccessful. thanks for any tip or help.

```
def store_data(value):
    file_exists = os.path.isfile('mycsvfile.csv')
    my_dict = read_data(filename)
    print 'my_dict: ', my_dict
    with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:  
        headers = ['year', 'values']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n',fieldnames=headers)
        if not file_exists:
            writer.writeheader()  # file doesn't exist yet, write a header

        writer.writerow({'year': my_dict[0], 'values': my_dict[1]})
```

this give me the following error.

```
'ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'values', 'year'
```

'

Comment: `delimiter=','` will put commas in your file, you seem to need spaces.

Comment: You're not appending to the file, so it gets wiped out if it already exists, and you don't write new headers.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre then what should I use instead of delimiter= ','

Comment: actually, it's not the only problem. The dictionary contains _all_ the dates and _all_ the values, whereas you should have a list of dictionaries with 1 item per key.

Comment: @ jean and the type of my_dict is 'type of:  <class 'collections.Counter'>
' and i don't know how to deal with it

Answer (score 0):

I solve my question and the code is as follow, might be helpful for someone.

```
def store_data(value):
    file_exists = os.path.isfile('mycsvfile.csv')
    my_dict = read_data(filename)
    print 'my_dict: ', my_dict
    print 'type of: ', type(my_dict)
    with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        headers = ['year', 'values']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n',fieldnames=headers)
        if not file_exists:
            writer.writeheader()
        for k, v in my_dict.items():
            print(k, v)
            writer.writerow({'year': k, 'values': v})
```

Actually I was missing to add loop in the proper way, so it results always in the csv file without headers. now it works perfectly fine according to my requirements.